# Prevent click jump on jQuery one() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, clickonce, preventdefault

I'm using the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function in jQuery to prevent multiple clicks.  However, when they click the element a second time, it does the annoying click jump and sends you back to the top of the page.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Unbinding the click and re-binding it when the function is done has the same result (and I'm assuming that `one()` just unbinds the event anyways).

A quick example of this happening: http://jsfiddle.net/iwasrobbed/FtbZa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is better or not, but you could bind a simple function that maintains the `return false`.

jQuery provides a shortcut for this with `.bind('click',false)`.

```
$('.someLink').one('click', function() {
    $(this).bind('click',false);
    return false;
});
```

or if you have several of these links, a very efficient alternative would be to use the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to bind a handler to a common ancestor that takes care of the `return false;` for you.

Here I just used the `body`, but you could use a nearer ancestor.

```
$('.someLink').one('click', function() {
});

$('body').delegate('.someLink','click',function(){return false;});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the href so the '#' isn't being used: http://jsfiddle.net/FtbZa/1/

```
$('.someLink').one('click', function() {
    alert('test');
    return false;
}).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
```

Comment: making the href="javascript:;" usually does it for me. Not sure of any side effects, however.

Comment: +1 Thanks McHerbie, I want to shy away from inline javascript for now though

Answer (score 2):

You could use the standard [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) function and a little logic:

```
1. $('.someLink').click(function(event) {
2.     event.preventDefault();
3.     if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked"))
4.         alert('This will be displayed only once.');
5.         $(this).addClass("clicked");
   });
```

1. Listen to anything with the class `someLink` for a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click)

   Stop the browser doing what it would normally do.

   Check if the object has the class `clicked` *(**Note this could be any name you wanted**)*

   It hasn't so do something.

   Add the class `clicked` so next time its clicked, it will ignore your code.

See the demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/FtbZa/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after the listener has been unbound there is nothing stopping the browser from honoring the link (Which it is treating as an anchor tag) and trying to go to it.  (Which in this case will simply lead to the top of the page.